# Second derivative of $\arctan(x^2)$

Tags: derivatives

Given that $y=\arctan(x^2)$ find $\ \dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}$.

I got

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2x}{1+x^4}.$$

Using *low d high minus high d low over low squared*, I got

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{(1+x)^4 \cdot 2 - 2x \cdot 4(1+x)^3}{(1+x^4)^2}.$$

I tried to simplify this but didn't get the answer which is

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=\frac{2(1-3x^4)}{(1+x^4)^2}.$$

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You treated the denominator as though it were $(1 + x)^4$, whereas it is given as $(1 + x^4)$ when you took the second derivative, though you got it right when you squared the denominator.

Answer (score 2):

You did the low d high minus high d low wrong:
The numerator should be:

$$(1+x^4)2 - (2x)(4x^3)$$

Answer (score 0):

Once you get to the second step, you can indeed use the chain rule.  Perhaps if you write out what you *intend* to find, rather than simply finding it, it'll become easier to see:

$$\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^4} \right)' = \frac{(2x)'\left(1+x^4\right) + (2x)\left( 1+x^4\right)'}{\left(1 + x^4 \right)^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively,

$ \large \tan (y) = x^2 \Rightarrow \sec^2 (y) \cdot \frac { \mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = 2x $

$ \large \Rightarrow \frac { \mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac {2x}{\sec^2 (y)} = \frac {2x}{\tan^2 (y) + 1} = \frac {2x}{x^4 + 1} $

$  \large \Rightarrow \frac { \mathrm{d^2}y}{\mathrm{d}x^2} = \frac {2(x^4+ 1) - 2x(4x^3)}{(x^4+1)^2} = \frac {-6x^4 + 2}{(x^4 + 1)^2} $